# Replacing &nbsp; from javascript dom text node

Tags: javascript, regex, html-entities

I am processing xhtml using javascript. I am getting the text content for a div node by concatenating the nodeValue of all child nodes where nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE.

The resulting string sometimes contains a non-breaking space entity. How do I replace this with a regular space character?

My div looks like this...

> `<div><b>Expires On</b> Sep 30, 2009 06:30&nbsp;AM</div>`

The following suggestions found on the web did not work:

```
var cleanText = text.replace(/^\xa0*([^\xa0]*)\xa0*$/g,"");


var cleanText = replaceHtmlEntities(text);

var replaceHtmlEntites = (function() {
  var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g;
  var translate = {
    "nbsp": " ",
    "amp" : "&",
    "quot": "\"",
    "lt"  : "<",
    "gt"  : ">"
  };
  return function(s) {
    return ( s.replace(translate_re, function(match, entity) {
      return translate[entity];
    }) );
  }
})();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "`&nnbsp;`" Your data isn't the problem... is it?

Comment: i put the typo in my post - Stack Overflow was converting the entity into an actual space in the post preview if I used &nbsp;

Comment: Hey, it looks like a typo in the function name.  See the edit to my question.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

This is much easier than you're making it. The text node will not have the literal string `"&nbsp;"` in it, it'll have have the corresponding character with code 160.

```
function replaceNbsps(str) {
  var re = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "g");
  return str.replace(re, " ");
}

textNode.nodeValue = replaceNbsps(textNode.nodeValue);
```

**UPDATE**

Even easier:

```
textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/\u00a0/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 42):

If you only need to replace `&nbsp;` then you can use a far simpler regex:

`var textWithNBSpaceReplaced = originalText.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');`

Also, there is a typo in your div example, it says `&nnbsp;` instead of `&nbsp;`.

Comment: How does that interact with &nbsp; character strings in CDATA blocks (since this is XHTML)?

Comment: It doesn't really cover that case.  If there is a need to go that far, a regex is probably the wrong solution.

Comment: i put the typo in my post - Stack Overflow was converting the entity into an actual space in the post preview if I used &nbsp;

Comment: When I inspect the variable in Firebug, I do not see the &nbsp; - the string looks like a valid date.  Pasting the value in a hex editor using UTF8 encoding revealed that the nbsp has been replaced with a 2 byte unicode char \uC2A0

Answer (score 17):

That first line is pretty messed up. It only needs to be:

```
var cleanText = text.replace(/\xA0/g,' ');
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: This is less code than the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I *think* when you define a function with "`var foo = function() {...};`", the function is only defined *after* that line.  In other words, try this:

```
var replaceHtmlEntites = (function() {
  var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g;
  var translate = {
    "nbsp": " ",
    "amp" : "&",
    "quot": "\"",
    "lt"  : "<",
    "gt"  : ">"
  };
  return function(s) {
    return ( s.replace(translate_re, function(match, entity) {
      return translate[entity];
    }) );
  }
})();

var cleanText = text.replace(/^\xa0*([^\xa0]*)\xa0*$/g,"");
cleanText = replaceHtmlEntities(text);
```

**Edit**: Also, only use "`var`" the first time you declare a variable (you're using it twice on the `cleanText` variable).

**Edit 2**:  The problem is the spelling of the function name.  You have "var replaceHtml*Entites* =".  It should be "var replaceHtml*Entit**i**es* ="

Comment: Yes, in my script I have the function before the place where I use it. Just forgot to make it that way when I posted here. But it did not work.

Answer (score 7):

i used this, and it worked:

```
var cleanText = text.replace(/&amp;nbsp;/g,"");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var text = "&quot;&nbsp;&amp;&lt;&gt;";
text = text.replaceHtmlEntites();

String.prototype.replaceHtmlEntites = function() {
var s = this;
var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g;
var translate = {"nbsp": " ","amp" : "&","quot": "\"","lt"  : "<","gt"  : ">"};
return ( s.replace(translate_re, function(match, entity) {
  return translate[entity];
}) );
};
```

try this.....this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Removes everything between `&` and `;` which all such symbols have. if you juts want to get rid of them.

```
text.replace(/&.*;/g,'');
```

Comment: If &nbsp; is there in multiple place then all matching sting will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

for me replace doesn't work...
try this code:

```
str = str.split("&quot;").join('"');
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to hack this in is to replace any empty line with two or more spaces with some newlines and a token.  Then post markdown, replace paragraphs with just that token to line breaks.

```js
// replace empty lines with "EMPTY_LINE"
rawMdText = rawMdText.replace(/\n  +(?=\n)/g, "\n\nEMPTY_LINE\n");
// put <br> at the end of any other line with two spaces
rawMdText = rawMdText.replace(/  +\n/, "<br>\n");

// parse
let rawHtml = markdownParse(rawMdText);

// for any paragraphs that end with a newline (injected above) 
// and are followed by multiple empty lines leading to
// another paragraph, condense them into one paragraph
mdHtml = mdHtml.replace(/(<br>\s*<\/p>\s*)(<p>EMPTY_LINE<\/p>\s*)+(<p>)/g, (match) => {
  return match.match(/EMPTY_LINE/g).map(() => "<br>").join("");
});

// for basic newlines, just replace them
mdHtml = mdHtml.replace(/<p>EMPTY_LINE<\/p>/g, "<br>");
```

What this does is finds every new line with nothing but a couple spaces+.  It uses look ahead so that it starts at the right place for the next replace, it'll break on two lines in a row without that.

Then markdown will parse those lines into paragraphs containing nothing but the token "EMPTY_LINE".  So you can go through the rawHtml and replace those with line breaks.

As a bonus, the replace function will condense all line break paragraphs into an uppper and lower paragraph if they exist.

In effect, you'd use it like this:

```
A line with spaces at end  
  
  
and empty lines with spaces in between will condense into a multi-line paragraph.

A line with no spaces at end
  
  
and lines with spaces in between will be two paragraphs with extra lines between.
```

And the output would be this:

```html
<p>
  A line with spaces at end<br>
  <br>
  <br>
  and empty lines with spaces in between will condense into a multi-line paragraph.
</p>

<p>A line with no spaces at end</p>
<br>
<br>
<p>and lines with spaces in between will be two paragraphs with extra lines between.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This goes through every value in an array of objects and converts

Maybe this helps someone ...*Pure javascript function.*

```js
var array = [{text: 'test &amp; & "', id:1}, {text: 'test222 &quot; \' 22222 "', id:2}];

    console.log('in', JSON.stringify(array));
    
array.map((object, i) => {
            //console.log('i', i, object);
            Object.keys(object).map(key => {
                var value = String(object[key]);
                
                var replacewith = {'&amp;': '&', '&lt;': '<', '&gt;': '>', '&quot;': '"', '&#039;': '\''};
                
                ['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&#039;'].map(checkme => {
                    if(value.indexOf(checkme) != -1){
                        console.log('htmlConvertBack found ' + checkme, value);
                        
                        var re = new RegExp(checkme, 'g');
                        
                        object[key] = value.replace(re, replacewith[checkme]);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    
    console.log('out', JSON.stringify(array));
```