# Leading space is not getting retained in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one application, i am facing one problem on Internet Explorer while retrieving inner HTML of div.

I have below input for retrieving :

```
<div> This is first segment</div>
```

I have used jquery script to extract content.
i.e.

```
$('div').html();
```

**Output after using above statement :**

```
This is first segment
```

Here not retrieving leading space present in div.
I am expecting here is :

```
 This is first segment
```

I am facing this problem on Internet Explorer, It's working properly on FireFox.

Please suggest your thoughts on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing to do about this. Maybe you can do it the safe way:

```
<div>&nbsp;This is first segment&nbsp;</div>
```

or try jQuery `text()`

Or try the non jQuery functions `innerHTML` `innerText`

Comment: Thanks a lot michel for your quick response.  I just want to add one more point here is that, i have used in later stage encoding/decoding of this data so there i'll need to take care of this encoding.  Is there any other way apart from this solution.....may  be with jquery or in javascript itself.

Comment: You want to put encoded content in the DIV and later you want Javascript(jQuery) to read this information by useing the html()?

Comment: I am sorry, i think I have not mentioned in detail, lemme give some more details of this
Below is overview of processing on the input data :
1) Get the contents from the DIV
2) Apply Encoding to this..and process on that ( here some logic has been applied )
3) Again I have decoded this data. ( Added some other logic )

This way i have applied encoding/decoding for the data.  Here my  point is if i use &nbsp; as mentioned above. I need to spend more efforts to take care of this in encoding/decoding, so that i wont impact on other features in my application.

Comment: mmmz ... you may want to look overhere:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495822/replacing-nbsp-from-javascript-dom-text-node

Answer (score 0):

You put

```
&nbsp;
```

before the text to force a non breakable space. This is recognised by all browsers.