# replacing spaces with &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Let's assume the following element (look for the trailing and leading spaces):

```
<p>
    <span class="item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </span><span class="item">of the printing and typesetting</span><span class="item"> industry.</span>
</p>
```

I want to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`, due to `display: inline-block` weird behavior shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQuUZ/ (I don't know about all browsers, but latest Chrome and Firefox both act the same).

Now, since javascript is an option here, so is jQuery, I could:

```
$('p').text($('p').text().replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;'));
```

But it escapes the `&nbsp;` and turns out into `a&nbsp;mess&nbsp;of&nbsp;entities`.

Obviously, for such purposes we could use `$('p').html()`:

```
$('p').html($('p').html().replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;'));
```

But this one is even worse, because, it also adds `&nbsp;` within the tags themselves:

```
<p>
    <span&nbsp;class="item">Lorem&nbsp;Ipsum&nbsp;is&nbsp;simply&nbsp;dummy&nbsp;text&nbsp;</span><span&nbsp;class="item">of&nbsp;the&nbsp;printing&nbsp;and&nbsp;typesetting</span><span&nbsp;class="item">&nbsp;industry.</span>
</p>

<!-- TL;DR -->
<span&nbsp;class="item"></span> <!-- is actually invalid... -->
```

And it breaks everything...

#### Notes:

- There won't only be `<span>` elements with class `item` inside the container (that may also not always be `<p>`).
- Slow regular expressions is an option (the problem is, I cannot come up with one...).

**What options do I have here?**

#### Update:

<strike>In fact, could anyone explain why there is such a bug with that multi-line / single-line `display: inline-block;`? (See fiddle link above, and examine...)</strike>

Question migrated to [display: inline-block; weird spacing behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474411/display-inline-block-weird-spacing-behavior)

Comment: Don't use regexes on blocks of html like this, as you're finding out. You get the entire child tree, including tags. You should instead look for only text nodes within the child tree and manipulate those individually.

Comment: I'm aware about regex'es for HTML manipulation. As for the NODE_TEXT manipulation, I couldn't find a way to insert `html` content for those. Everything resulted as with `.text()` except, without breaking the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the question, it was fun!

Comment: @Qtax, once my application will be ready for public beta, you'll be able to read it in description, and I'll make you know when it's ready.

Comment: It is not evident what the real problem is, as you are referring to a jsfiddle, not a problem description. And why would you replace spaces by entities instead of replacing them by actual no-break spaces?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$('p').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 // Text node
}).each(function(){
    this.data = this.data.replace(/ /g, '\u00a0');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/SQuUZ/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SQuUZ/2/ doesn't look fine to me, because `&nbsp;` stays as text, not becoming an HTML entity. And that's what I mentioned in the reply comment for Marc B, that I couldn't find a way to transform that `&nbsp;` into entity (except I explained it badly). `&nbsp;` becomes `&amp;nbsp;` instead, as with `.text()`.

Comment: @psycketom. Let me check the jQuery source code, It might take a while... Put some dramatic music in the background as I'm going in.

Comment: Oki, doki, it works if `*.replace(/ /g, '\u00a0');`. `\u00a0` resolves to `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @psycketom. I've just found the same solution. ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1496863/601179))

Comment: @gdoron I read about it also there, before asking tho', but was fed up with NODE_TEXT failures, so didn't try it out this way.

Comment: @psycketom. By the way, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/298750/601179) if you want deep textnodes.

Answer (score 28):

Even tho *[jQuery is really great and does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)*, CSS could also work in some cases:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SQuUZ/3/)**.

CSS3 related: [`text-space-collapse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110901/#white-space-collapsing)

Comment: I'm using `white-space` too for my app. But, I needed that JS solution, because of not display issues, but because I need those elements visually editable.

Comment: 100X better then using &nbsp;

Comment: This should be the answer for many IMHO because in our app, users manage to get all sorts of "space" alternatives into their data, especially if copy/pasting from Office365 online editors.

Answer (score 3):

> could anyone explain why there is such a bug with that multi-line / single-line display: inline-block;? (See fiddle link above, and examine...)

Consider:

```
​<p><span style="display:inline-block">lorem </span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<span>ipsum</span></p>
```

The space character is *inside* the line box container created by `display:inline-block`. [CSS 2.1 16.6.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model) describes how spaces in a line box must be processed:

> As each line is laid out … [i]f a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is … removed.

As the space is at the end of the line *inside* the inline block, it is removed.

Contrast:

```
<p><span style="display:inline-block">lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span></p>​
```

In this case, the space is not removed, because it is between two inline-level elements that make up a single line box.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `<pre> </pre>` element to make spaces visible. Its a fast solution if you want to visually display, lets say, ascii art.