# display: inline-block; weird spacing behavior

Tags: html, css

Since I got my spaces replaced with `&nbsp;`'s, the previous question is answered, but...

I still have no idea what causes this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/cEkQG/

Look how the first paragraph has lost it's children (that are `inline-blocks`) trailing/leading spaces. Note, that the markup for `spans` are in a single line of paragraph.

The second paragraph has the spaces, but, the markup of `spans` here are each in a separate line.

The bug occurs on latest Chrome and latest Firefox (freshly updated to 12), have not tested with other browsers yet.

What is the reason behind this weird bug/behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leading and trailing whitespace in blocks (inline-blocks in particular) are stripped. Move trailing space inside your inline block to outside of the inline block — after its closing tag. Line feed is whitespace too, that’s why the multiline example works as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `display: inline` instead of `inline-block` since the element will be "inline" with text not with other block elements. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/cEkQG/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span> <span class="item">of the printing and typesetting</span><span class="item"> industry.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire reason this does not work is because  .  It stands for non-breaking space and thus it cannot wrap a non-breaking space, because is it non-breaking and thus does not wrap.