# PHP &nbsp; in a textarea file editor

Tags: php, html

This is a pretty minor inconvenience, but I'd still like to know how you guys would handle this.

I have made a quick file editor in PHP meant to edit the site's template files for convenience.

Some of my templates have `&nbsp;` in them. When loaded into a textarea, they get converted into spaces, which is pretty reasonable. However, when I save the file, they get converted into literal spaces.

Because I'm editing HTML, I can't use `htmlentities()` without ruining all the existing brackets.

Is there a way I can selectively encode entities that are part of an already encoded entity? Or am I going to have to regex the template looking for a `/&.;/` pattern?

Edit: Example

Template:
    `<h2>&nbsp;Hello!&nbsp;</h2>`

Inside the textarea, it should look like:

`<h2>&amp;nbsp;Hello!&amp;nbsp;</h2>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing spaces with &nbsp;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474124/replacing-spaces-with-nbsp)

Comment: Do you want to stop converting them to spaces or convert them back to &nbsp;? Remember that if you are converting them back you will need to track which was a space and which was not. If you don't want to convert them on loading the template just don't escape it.

Comment: Can you post an example with desired input and output? It's difficult to know what you want to do with the `&nbsp;`s

Comment: I've added an example for clarity