# How to do line-clamping with &nbsp character?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do line-clamping and that is the [example](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp) of what it is.

So it happened that in my application instead of whitespaces " ", `&nbsp` are being generated.

The thing is when I try to do this, the first line is displayed ugly because in that line phrase is being divided into two words. And in my main project I can't do anything about `&nbsp` vanishing.

[image]

So is there any CSS solution to make it look good?

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/dYJWqM).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row description">
        <p>
Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words&nbsp;Some words
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
$font-size: 14px;
$line-height: 1.3;
$lines-to-show: 8;

.description {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    height: $font-size*$line-height*$lines-to-show;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: $font-size;
    line-height: $line-height;
    -webkit-line-clamp: $lines-to-show;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin: 30px 60px;

  .jumbotron {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want CSS to treat &nbsp; just like regular whitespace?

Comment: Unfortunately everything that I've found already points to it not being possible. What you _can_ do is convert all &nbsp;s to regular whitespace using javascript, thus avoiding your problem beforehand.

Comment: @klaar That's so pity, because I wouldn't want to overload my application with JS ;( Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be of using `text-align: justify;`, but the problem of space button generating `&nbsp;` might be the same than I'm having occasionally.

If seems like the Google Chrome browser in some situations uses the `&nbsp;` instead of the regular whitespace. Using a different browser might work off in the future.

**EDIT:** There is the non-CSS solution for exactly what you're seeking to solve, just use [this original topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474124/replacing-spaces-with-nbsp) reversely.

Answer (score 3):

The one thing I would suggest is for you to use:

```
text-align: justify;
```

This will stretch the text for being full width of the container.

Comment: That is so sad because I also tried this approach and that looks even more shitty.  [Image](http://imgur.com/zDqqtGJ)