# javascript: check for blank textNode

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the best way to check if a DOM text node is blank? By blank I mean only spaces, returns, tabs, etc. If it contains a nbsp; then it is NOT blank.

I was doing:

```
element.nodeValue.trim().length != 0
```

However, this also gets rid of nbsp;, which I do not want.

(It's for a Chrome extension so use of trim is OK - no IE!)

Comment: Simply add a check for non breaking spaces

Comment: nbsp; shows up in nodeValue, so what's the problem?

Comment: If the only holdup is the non-breaking space, do this: `element.nodeValue.indexOf("\u00A0") > -1 || element.nodeValue.trim().length > 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up replacing nbsp; with a char and then trimming.

```
element.nodeValue.replace(/\u00a0/g, "x").trim().length != 0
```

Based on [Replacing &nbsp; from javascript dom text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495822/replacing-nbsp-from-javascript-dom-text-node)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

HTML

```
<div id="test1">        
    </div>
<div id="test2">    &nbsp;      
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
var test2 = document.getElementById("test2");

function escapeHTML(str) {
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return pre.innerHTML;
}

console.log(escapeHTML(test1.textContent).trim().length === 0);
console.log(escapeHTML(test2.textContent).trim().length === 0);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/js7Ua/)

output is

```
true
false
```

Or with nodeValue

Javascript

```
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1").firstChild;
var test2 = document.getElementById("test2").firstChild;

function escapeHTML(str) {
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return pre.innerHTML;
}

console.log(escapeHTML(test1.nodeValue).trim().length === 0);
console.log(escapeHTML(test2.nodeValue).trim().length === 0);
```

output

```
true
false
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uSbVj/)

See [Node.nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue) and [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

Node.nodeValue

> Returns or sets the value of the current node.
>
> The following table shows the return values for different elements:
>   ...
>
> Text: content of the text node

Node.textContent

> Gets or sets the text content of a node and its descendants.

In the first case I get the text content of the div element and it descendants.

In the second case I choose the first text node of the div, which happens to be the first child node, and get it's node value.

Comment: You're testing an element. OP is testing a text node.

Comment: Yes, that'll work. I wonder if it works with all whitespace HTML entities.

Comment: I believe it should (not tested all), but it would be easy to test, just fork the jsfiddle and put them in there.

Answer (score -4):

```
if ( element.textContent.trim() ) ...
```

EDIT, really meant to say:

```
if ( element.innerHTML.trim() ) ...
```

Comment: That's functionally identical to what the OP posted.