# String compare gives wrong output when white space is present in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects, jquery-events

I am having two string :

```
x = "hi hemant how r u"
y = "hi hemant how r u"
```

If we see, both look same, but

```
x === y gives false.
```

I check ascii values of both, this are different

```
x = "hi hemant how r u"
034 104 105 032 104 101 109 097 110 116 194 160 104 111 119 032 114 032 117 034

y = "hi hemant how r u"

034 104 105 032 104 101 109 097 110 116 032 104 111 119 032 114 032 117 034
```

the difference is with 194 160 is represent white space in x,  while 032 represent white space in y.
I want some thing which return true, when i write x === y

https://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/ekzoveew/

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle, since I am getting `x === y` as true

Comment: How one space is different than other?

Comment: Space will have the same ASCII value everywhere....How is it different?

Comment: i will add jsfiddle link

Comment: i had added js fiddle plz check

Answer (score 2):

Your text is UTF-8 and `194 160` translates to `0x00A0`, which is the Unicode code point for non-breaking space. This is **not** the same as an ordinary space character. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774471/what-is-c2-a0-in-mime-encoded-quoted-printable-text) for a related SO answer and [here for an extended Unicode info page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) on NO-BREAK SPACE.

You could replace all whitespace via regex with ordinary space and compare then, here's a SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496863/2535335 - in your case:

```
x = x.replace(/\u00a0/g, " ");
```

Comment: Then how both spaces can be different in the same utf8 environment?

Comment: Ordinary space and non-breaking space are different characters, what's more to say?

Comment: I wanted to know how they are produced?

Comment: In HTML, you could add `&nbsp;`, if a user copies the text, it would be converted to the Unicode NO-BREAK-SPACE. On Windows, I am sure you can insert it directly via alt-something

Comment: The user is not using &nbsp; See jsfiddle.

Comment: Is there any way to convert to ordinary without using regex.

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal : I copied text from my code. And first line i am getting is with &nbsp

Comment: @HemantMalpote I visited that jsfiddle link you provided. I removed all the space and added the space again and it worked. Did you type out those lines by yourself or copy-pasted?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal see here for an example what I mean: https://jsbin.com/bigogopubo/edit?html,output

Comment: @Mathews Mathai : I copied it .

Comment: @HemantMalpote you could write a function to encapsulate it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1496863/2535335

Comment: @HemantMalpote That could be a reason why 2 different space type appeared.

Comment: @Johannes Jander : thanks, it works with the replacing.

Comment: I am getting first value from ckeditor and other from db. is there any way to get space instead of &nbsp from ckeditor.

Comment: @HemantMalpote unfortunately that seems like a long-standing bug in ckeditor, see [this bug report from 2y ago](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9929#comment:15) and [this discussion](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Recommendations-for-how-to-deal-with-unwanted-nbsp-entities)

Comment: @Johannes Jander : Ok ,  Thanks

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept (and upvote if you like it) it - this gets me  a couple of reputation points and visitors in the future looking for a solution to a similar problem see there is a working answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I want some thing which return true, when i write x === y

```
var x = "hi hemant how r u";
var y = "hi hemant how r u";
```

replace everything matching with space with a normal space `" "`

```
x.split( /\s+/ ).join( " " ) == y.split( /\s+/ ).join( " " ) //outputs true
```

Here I converted anything that matches the space with a single space `" "` .

```
var x = "hi hemant how r u";
var y = "hi hemant how r u";
x = x.split( /\s+/ ).join( " " );
y = y.split( /\s+/ ).join( " " );

alert( x == y ); //alerts true
alert( x === y ); //alerts true
```