# Remove Leading and Trailing Spaces from Summernote html output

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I'm using a Summernote jQuery plugin, I want to remove leading and trailing spaces and blank tags only containing `&nbsp;` from the HTML output.I have tried string.Trim() function and its not working.

In the code, when I placed a debugger, I'm getting the following values from the multiline text box. Below code is just an example, I may also apply Bold, color, etc to my text, accordingly the HTML code may vary. Here is the Sample text

```
var str="<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br></div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br></div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Sample Text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br></div><div><br></div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br></div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br></div>";

output="<div>Sample&nbsp;Text</div>"
```

Now how to remove the leading and trailing spaces from HTML ?

Comment: Which Rich text editor you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/webfashionist/RichText

Comment: I'd suggest searching for a text editor which generates better markup. While it may be possible to work around this, if you can avoid fixing a GIGO situation, all the better.

Comment: not possible to change this editor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing &nbsp; from javascript dom text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495822/replacing-nbsp-from-javascript-dom-text-node)

Comment: No, this is not duplicate, solutions replacing all the &nbsp; from each node, I want only from first and last node