# How to replace unknown whitespace on string

Tags: javascript

I am getting a string from an API that has some sort of spacing, `string2`. On `string2` the spaces are not regular spaces, I don't even know if they are tabs, but if I try to replace them still not equal to the spaced `string1`.

```js
// This string has normal spaces charCodeAt(4) displays '32'
const string1 = 'long string with spaces'
// This string has different spaces charCodeAt(4) displays '160'
const string2 = 'long string with spaces'.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')

console.log(string1)
console.log(string2)
console.log(string1 === string2)
```

--- Update

The problem was that I had a mixture of normal spaces and non-breaking spaces on `string1` so it will never be equal to `string2` no matter how much I changed `string2`

Since I do have control of the `string1`, I have corrected it to have normal spaces and now it works.

Comment: that will return true not false

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496863) may help.

Comment: This probably means you have some invisible character in either string (maybe in the non-ASCII range). I turned your code into a snippet and it returns true. So please provide code in your question that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @trincot, thanks I have amended it, it now says false

Comment: Check the `.charCode()` of the characters. You will find some "spaces" with a code of 160 which is a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`)

Comment: Indeed, inspection of string2 shows that it doesn't have regular spaces. If you would have applied the same replacement on it, the strings would have been equal.

Comment: @Andreas yeah I get `32` for the first string and `160` for the second, how can I force the second string to change the space to a normal space?

Comment: Oh I see `string1` has also a bad space, that is why it will never be true

Answer (score 1):

Codepoint `160` (`\u00a0`) is a non-breaking space.

If you [don't need to support IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#browser_compatibility), you can use the [Unicode property escape](https://2ality.com/2017/07/regexp-unicode-property-escapes.html) `/\p{White_Space}+/gu` as a Unicode-aware alternative to `/\w+/`. This will match `\u00a0` along with any other whitespace character.

If you need to support IE, you can generate your own whitespace-matching regex instead, using an environment that *does*  support Unicode property escapes. For example, running the following in the Chrome browser console:

```js
const toUnicodeEscape = x => '\\u' + x.toString(16).padStart(4, '0')

const last = arr => arr.slice(-1)[0]

const charGroupings = [...new Array(0xffff).keys()]
    .map(k => String.fromCodePoint(k))
    .filter(x => /^\p{White_Space}+$/u.test(x))
    .map(x => x.codePointAt(0))
    .reduce((acc, n) => {
        const prev = last(acc)

        if (prev && last(prev) === n - 1) {
            prev.push(n)
        } else {
            acc.push([n])
        }

        return acc
    }, [])
    .map(x => x.length <= 2
        ? x.map(toUnicodeEscape).join('')
        : `${toUnicodeEscape(x[0])}-${toUnicodeEscape(last(x))}`)
    .join('')

new RegExp(`[${charGroupings}]+`, 'g')
```

Generates the regex `/[\u0009-\u000d\u0020\u0085\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]+/g`, which is exactly equivalent to `/\p{White_Space}+/gu`.

Answer (score 0):

I can just turn all characters with charCode with more than 126 into spacebar

```js
function formatWhiteSpaces(string){
  return string.split('')
  .map(a=>{ if(a.charCodeAt()<127){return(a)}return(" ") }) //when charcode of something > 126 (127+), it returns strange characters.. String.fromCharCode(160) returns something looking like " " and String.fromCharCode(173 returns something looking like "")
  .join('')
}
var string1 = formatWhiteSpaces('long string with spaces')
var string2 = formatWhiteSpaces('long string with spaces')
console.log(string1)
console.log(string2)
console.log(string1 === string2)
```

JUST IN CASE I actually turn wanted characters into spacebar, I can make it very specific(since only `String.fromCharCode(160)` makes the spacebar looking thing)

```js
function formatWhiteSpaces(string){
  return string.split('')
  .map(a=>{
    if(a.charCodeAt()==160){return(" ")} //160 similar to " "
    if(a.charCodeAt()==173){return("")}//173 similar to ""
    return(a)
  })
  .join('')
}
var string1 = formatWhiteSpaces('long string with spaces')
var string2 = formatWhiteSpaces('long string with spaces')
console.log(string1)
console.log(string2)
console.log(string1 === string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string contain words and spaces (different), We can extract the words and rebuild the string then compare.

```js
const cleanStr = str => [...str.matchAll(/\w+/g)].map(x => x[0]).join(' ')

// This string has normal spaces charCodeAt(4) displays '32'
const string1 = 'long string with spaces'
// This string has different spaces charCodeAt(4) displays '160'
const string2 = 'long string with spaces'

console.log(string1)
console.log(string2)
console.log(cleanStr(string1) === cleanStr(string2))
```

Comment: This will work the same for spaces `const cleanStr = str => str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` without having to convert the string to array