# React inconsistent when encoding spaces

Tags: reactjs, string, jsx

I noticed some inconsistent behavior with React. Take this simple component:

```
export default function App() {
  const string1 = "A B";
  const string2 = "A B";
  return (
    <>
      {string1}
      {string2}
    </>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-dust-fydhg?file=/src/App.js)

`string1` will be rendered to the page as `"A B"`, but `string2` is rendered as `"A&nbsp;B"`:

[image: Screenshot]

Why does one get rendered as a regular space (U+0020) and the other as a non-breaking space (U+00A0) HTML entity (`&nbsp;`)? How can I force it to render a regular space in both cases instead of a non-breaking space?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking space"? A line break? There's a "regular space" (unicode 32), but I don't think "breaking space" is a thing. If I copy your 2 strings, I'm not seeing `&nbsp;` on my end.

Comment: @sallf By "breaking space" I just mean a regular space (U+0020) which allows for automatic line breaks, as opposed to a non-breaking space (U+00A0), which prevents automatic line breaks. Both of these are regular spaces in the source file, but when parsed by the JSX parser, the space in `string2` is converted to the `&nbsp;` HTML entity whereas the space in `string1` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the `&nbsp` in your "source file". If you delete `string2` in your codepen and retype it with your keyboard, `&nbsp;` goes away. Regular space   and non-breaking space   look the same when rendered, but as you observed, if you look at these through the console they will be different.

If you're worried about `nbsp` ending up on your site, you might either clean the strings in your "source file" or [use javascript to find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495822/replacing-nbsp-from-javascript-dom-text-node)

What's extra confusing, is both typing `&nbsp;` and pasting a rendered   look identical in your browser's inspector.

[image: nbsp; vs nbsp;]

Comment: By golly, you're right. I must have copied and pasted the string thinking it was a regular space.