# Replace multiple &nbsp with multiple whitespace

Tags: javascript, php, html

I retrieve an HTML string from the database and needed to change all `&nbsp;`s' to white spaces

```html
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am</p><p>C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;F</p>
```

so I wanted the change the   to whitespaces, so i can use in a pre element

```
<pre></pre>
```

as following

```html
<pre >

    //here i needed to insert the converted string
    //for example
                C              G                 Am          F

    C                 G              F   C/E   Dm   C

</pre>
```

I need a solution to do this either in PHP, JS / Jquery

Please Help me through out this

I have tried

```
$nbsp = html_entity_decode("&nbsp;");
$s = html_entity_decode("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am</p>");
$s = str_replace($nbsp, " ", $s);
```

I tried This but this replaces all nbsp's to one white space

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $nbsp = html_entity_decode("&nbsp;");
    $s = html_entity_decode("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am</p>");
    $s = str_replace($nbsp, " ", $s);  

I tried This but this replaces all nbsp's to one white space

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: if you're displaying in blade template then there is syntax to display HTML code. `{!! $html !!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even inside `<pre>` tags, HTML tags will be turned into DOM elements and the browsers will collapse multiple spaces into one. Here is an example of this behavior.

```html
<pre>
  <h1>A heading</h1>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a table</td>
      <td>a table</td>
      <td>a table</td>
      <td>a table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</pre>
```

Also, in order to replace multiple occurrences of the search string, you'll have to use a regular expression in the first parameter of `.replace()`.

**Solution**

This uses a rudimentary way to replace HTML tags in the string, but that's outside the scope for this question. I added it to be able to reproduce your case and be able to provide a solution.

```js
const s = '<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am</p><p>C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;F</p>';

let result = s.replace(/(<p>|<br(.*)>)/gi, "\r\n")  // replace starting paragraph tags and line break tags with actual line breaks
              .replace(/(<\/p>)/gi, "\n") // replace closing paragraph tags with nothing
              .replace(/(<(.*)>)/gi, "") // discard any other HTML tags
              .replace(/\&nbsp;/gi, ' '); // replace non-breaking space entities with actual spaces

document.querySelector('#tabs').innerText = result; // insert
```

```html
<pre id="tabs">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using the html `pre` tag that preserves whitespace.
[https://www.techonthenet.com/html/elements/pre_tag.php#:~:text=The%20HTML%20tag%20defines,as%20the%20element](https://www.techonthenet.com/html/elements/pre_tag.php#:%7E:text=The%20HTML%20tag%20defines,as%20the%20element).
Then with javascript or php you could replace instances of   with a regular space.

```
mytext.replace('&nbsp;', ' ');
```

Comment: i have tried this but it replaces all nbsp's to one white spcae

Comment: replace (String,String) only works on first instance

Answer (score 0):

You need to not only replace `&nbsp;` but also remove any html tags, replacing them with non-tag line breaks. To facilitate this, I'm using the DOM. I create an element, inject it with the `&nbsp;` data, then loop through the `<p>` tags, get their innerText and replace the `&nbsp;` referencing it with the [unicode character it represents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495822/replacing-nbsp-from-javascript-dom-text-node) `\u00a0`

```js
const data = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am</p><p>C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Am&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;F</p>";
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;
div.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => document.querySelector('#result').append(p.innerText.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' ') + "\n\n"))
```

```css
pre {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<pre id='result'></pre>
```