# How to fix when words are cut using word-wrap? CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a code below that does word wrap, but the problem is, it cuts off the word just like an example output. Expected output, the second *"head"* should be in the next line and not cut.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
<div className="relative mt-px-14 mx-px-8 p-px-25">
  <div className="relative">
        <div className="absolute w-full text-20 whitespace-pre-line break-words">
          Head shoulder knees and toes head
        </div>
        .... more codes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Tailwind css [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace)

```
> break-all ==> word-break: break-all;
> whitespace-pre-line   ===>  white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Try using `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Try using Class "break-words"

Comment: i tried all your suggestions but not working.

Comment: Can you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can share code using https://play.tailwindcss.com/ so that we get a better idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the styles are working fine.

I found out that my custom keyboard does not returning *" "* space if I tap spacebar. It instead return `&nbsp;` which causes the problem.

What I did is I replace `&nbsp;` to space(" "), and it solves the problem. [Replacing &nbsp; from javascript dom text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495822/replacing-nbsp-from-javascript-dom-text-node)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the snippet below, the value for `word-break` you were looking for is `break-word`, not `break-all`.

As per the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp),

```
break-all   To prevent overflow, word may be broken at any character
break-word  To prevent overflow, word may be broken at arbitrary points
```

```css
.one {
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.two {
  margin-top: 20px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus deserunt consectetur iste obcaecati nam placeat adipisci beatae explicabo dolorem cum magnam a officiis nihil repudiandae eligendi, tempore ducimus maxime veniam.
</div>

<div class='two'>
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus deserunt consectetur iste obcaecati nam placeat adipisci beatae explicabo dolorem cum magnam a officiis nihil repudiandae eligendi, tempore ducimus maxime veniam.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also You can use `CSS` [hyphens](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/) property.

This is a quick demo:

```css
article {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

article p {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<article lang="en">
  <p>As designers attempting to creating functional work, oftentimes we are required to make our designs look as finished as possible.</p>
  <p>For example, if you are designing a brand new website for someone, most times you will have to make sure the prototype looks finished by inserting text or photos or what have you. The purpose of this is so the person viewing the prototype has a chance to actually feel and understand the idea behind what you have created.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` for

.

```css
article {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

article p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<article lang="en">
  <p>As designers attempting to creating functional work, oftentimes we are required to make our designs look as finished as possible.</p>
  <p>For example, if you are designing a brand new website for someone, most times you will have to make sure the prototype looks finished by inserting text or photos or what have you. The purpose of this is so the person viewing the prototype has a chance to actually feel and understand the idea behind what you have created.</p>
</article>
```